# Understanding this circuit with op. amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, basic

I'm studying electrical engineering and I've came to a problem, where I cannot proceed. It's a "simple" task, where we're talking about an inverting op.amp with 2 voltage sources, each 1V, while all resistors are 10k, except the one in the feedback, which is 20k.

I I know, that the solution is Uout = -7V, but how to get to this result?
By equations I've calculated, I've got result either -0.5 or -3V, but never -7. And also, I've simulated in LTSpice and got -7V.

Will appriciate all the help!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRNSYC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Tidied up schematic for OP review. [Transistor]*

Comment: Have you tried superposition? (Analyze with only one of the sources at a time and add the results.)

Comment: I've copied and tidied up your schematic for your review. Note vertical alignment of voltage sources with + on top. Note ground symbol point to, um, ground. (Some standards use the pointing up symbol to mean V+.) You may delete either the original or mine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll let someone else do the sums formally/generally, but there is an easy approach here that will allow you to solve it by inspection.

As you know, the op-amp inputs are both going to be 0V at balance (if there is negative feedback and the op-amp can balance). So let's assume that.

That means that 100uA is flowing through R3, and since our ideal op-amp input contributes nothing, 100uA must be flowing out of R2, by KCL.

So now we know the voltage at the junction of R1/R2/R5- it must be -1V.

So the current through R1 is 200uA, and the current flowing out through R5 must therefore be 300uA (100uA + 200uA). So the output is 6V below -1V or -7V.

(scrawl arrows on the schematic to keep the current directions straight, if it helps).

Comment: Many many thanks!
I've been confused at the R1-R2-R5 part, because "how do you know, that there's -1V?" then I remembered, that R3=R2 and therefore, if the "upper" voltage is +1V, the lower has to be -1V. It's a simple voltage devider!

Thank you very much again!